# How to define preprocessor directives in VC++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. The WIN32 preprocessor directive doesn't appear to be defined by default, so when I surround includes with #ifndef WIN32, it still includes them.

I found someone with the exact same problem below, but it was so long ago that the location of this setting has changed:

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=418604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS 2008 Pro, you right-click on the project and select Properties.  Then look for Preprocessor Definitions in Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Preprocessor.

Answer (score 3):

`Try _WIN32` instead (notice the underscore...)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.71).aspx).